# Convert all values in dict to their actual type

Tags: python, python-3.x

Let's assume i have got this dictionary, filled with various string values:

```
dictionary = { "name": "Andrew", "age": "34", "is_good_enought": "True", "something": "None" }
```

How to convert all string values to their exact data type they represent?

**Expected result:**

```
dictionary = { "name": "Andrew", "age": 34, "is_good_enought": True, "something": None}
```

Comment: `dictionary['age'] = int(dictionary['age'])`

Comment: Do i have to convert each value like this? How about i would like to change name of keys or add anditional items inside dict? I guess the best would be to create another dictionary using loop with properly converted values. But how? Maybe json.loads could help?

Comment: Could you blame the guy who gives you such a bad dictionary?

Comment: You can loop through every key/value pair using a simple for-loop. Then you should check the formatting: Is it numeric? / Is it a boolean? And if so -> store the corresponding value into the dict.

Comment: do you know which value needs to be which type? And what keys you have?

Comment: @Florian H No i dont, i want a function to detect values by string if they are int, str, bool or whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
from ast import literal_eval

for i, v in dictionary.items():
    try:
        dictionary[i] = literal_eval(v)
    except ValueError:
        pass
```

From the documentation:

> ast.literal_eval(node_or_string)
>
> Safely evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.
>
> This can be used for safely evaluating strings containing Python values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values oneself. It is not capable of evaluating arbitrarily complex expressions, for example involving operators or indexing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by simply creating a function that filters the values given by the string, and typesetting them to their corresponding types. For example, like your example:

```
def change_type(string):
    if string.lower() in ['true', 'false']: #for bool types
        return string.lower()=='true'
    elif string.isdigit(): #for int types
        return int(string)
    elif string.lower() == 'none': #For none-types
        return None
    else:
        return string
```

Then, using your custom function, you can run:

```
for k, v in dictionary.items():
    dictionary[k] = change_type(v)
```

For further filters, you can type **help(str)** and read on it, or you could use regex. Hope this helps.